# Why can't I import Pandas on a Raspberry PI4 after installing Pandas

Tags: pandas, installation, raspberry-pi4

Relatively new to Coding. However after I pip install pandas on my raspberry PI 4 Bullseye (using this version as the newer version 'Bookworm' has issues with using VNC server) and then simply run 'Import pandas as pd' I get the following error with something about numpy:

ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
your python interpreter from there.

I'm just using the terminal on the raspberry by to install (no venv).

I've managed to use pandas on my old Pi 3B in this way with no issues but, after much messing around with pip3 install & sudu pip install, re-imaging of the sd card, updating etc... I can't seem to get it to run on the PI4. It's using Python 3.9.2 (not sure if this should matter). Is this a widely encountered issue or is this just a 'me' issue.

I would have thought that, like many other libraries, it should just be a case of pip install ..... and you're ready to go. I've installed other packages on the Pi4 that have run fine and have never usually had a problem with pandas until now.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.